# Vue fails when change from views after implements swiper js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, swiper.js

I have a project with vue3 after implementing swiperjs 11 in my project and customize some properties, my routing is failing, showing me this

[Errors in console, first in my component, and when I supose to be in other view, send that in parent Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uIpQ.png)

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <swiper-container v-show="news.length > 0"
    :loop="true"
    :centered-slides="true"
    :centeredSlidesBounds="true"
    :pagination="{
      clickable: true
    }"
    :autoplay="{
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    }"
    init="false"
    :ref="(el) => setSwiperEl(el)"
    >
    <swiper-slide v-for="(slideNew, index) in news" :key="index">
      <div class="carrousel-background news-container" >
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="container pt-5 px-5 mx-5">
            <div class="row">
              <span class="news-title">
                {{slideNew.title}}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-5 pe-5 me-5">
              <p class="news-content">{{slideNew.body}}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end news-image-container">
          <img :src="'/src/assets/images/' + slideNew.image" class="news-image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
  
</template>
<script>
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle'
import { ref } from 'vue';
register();

export default {
  name: 'news-component',
  setup(){
    const swiperEl = ref(null);
    const swiperParams = {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      injectStyles: [
        `
          .swiper-pagination-bullet {
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            opacity: 1;
            background-color: transparent;
          }
          .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
          }
        `,
      ],
    };
    const setSwiperEl = (el) => {
      swiperEl.value = el;
      Object.assign(swiperEl.value, swiperParams);
      swiperEl.value.initialize();
    };
    return {
      setSwiperEl
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

It supose to change my view from the page that contains that component, to another one but it seems that the component never be unmount or destroy I dont know.